# Orthogonal complement of a "moving frame"

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let there be a set of vectors $v_i=M_i x$, where $M_i$, $i=1,\dots,k<n$ are $[n\times n]$ real matrices and $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ are variables. The vectors $v_i$ are known to be linearly independent.

The set $\{v_i\}$ forms a sort of a $k$-dimensional frame that depends on $x$. The vectors $v_i$ span a $k$-dimensional linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

> How can I characterize $span\{v_i\}^\perp$, i.e., the orthogonal complement of $span\{v_i\}$?

This orthogonal complement can be represented as a frame $\{w_j\}$, $j=1,\dots,n-k$, $w_j=Q_jx$ s.t. $w_j^T v_i=0$ for all $i,j$ within their ranges. This is equivalent to finding a set of matrices $Q_j$ s.t. $Q^T_j M_i=0$ for all $i,j$.

I cannot figure out how to approach this problem. Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** in my problem, the matrices $M_i$ are rank deficient and are of pretty simple form so I wonder if it is possible to obtain the requested characterization in terms of the matrices $M_i$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be the $n\times k$ augmented matrix $(v_1,\ldots,v_k)$. Then $AA^+$ (where $A^+$ denotes the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse of $A$) is the orthogonal projection onto the column space of $A$, and hence $I-AA^+$ is the orthogonal projection onto the orthogonal complement of the span of $v_1,\ldots,v_k$. That is, $\left(\operatorname{span}\{v_1,\ldots,v_k\}\right)^\perp$ is the column space of $I-AA^+$.

Comment: yes, this is pretty obvious, but in my case the vectors $v_i$ are determined by corresponding $M_i$ matrices so I wonder if it is possible to use them explicitly when defining the  orthogonal complement. I'll edit my question to express this more clear.